# How to append to a text field in t-sql SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, append

What is the best way to append to a text field using t-sql in Sql Server 2005?

With a varchar I would do this.

```
update tablename set fieldname = fieldname + 'appended string'
```

But this doesn't work with a text field.

Comment: Off the top of my head I would say that should work.  The issue is probably a conversion/casting issue.  Try fieldname = fieldname + N'appended string'

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work.  I got 'The data types text and nvarchar are incompatible in the add operator.'  Thanks though.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try this:

```
update 
  tablename
set
  fieldname = convert(nvarchar(max),fieldname) + 'appended string'
```

Comment: Well, at least I knew it was some sort of conversion error. :)  Thanks Bravax.

Comment: If fieldname is null this won't work.  instead of fieldname try
COALESCE(fieldname, '')

Answer (score 6):

[This should work (link)](http://developer.fusium.com/FUblog/index.cfm/2006/7/13/appending-an-ntext-field)

Copied from link:

```
DECLARE @ptrval binary(16)
SELECT @ptrval = TEXTPTR(ntextThing)
FROM item
WHERE id =1
UPDATETEXT table.ntextthing @ptrval NULL 0 '!'
GO
```

Answer (score 3):

in 2005 you should use varchar(max) or nvarchar(max) these columns will work with normal varchar functions. Text and ntext have been deprecated

Answer (score 0):

The max length for varchar(max) is 2,147,483,647 characters.
This is the same as the Text data type.

Whatever text could hold, this can hold,
so you don't need to worry about running out of room by switching to VARCHAR(MAX).